# Basis in topology and AC

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Let S ⊂ ℘(X). Let T be the coarsest topology on X which contains S. Then we call T the topology generated by S.

Let S ⊂ ℘(X). Then we can easily prove using **(generalised distributive law)** the topology generated by S is {union over a in A(intersection of    D(a, j) for j in I(a)) where A is arbitary index set and I(a) is finite set for each D(a, j) on S}.

**This fact used in proving very important result about basis:
(B ⊂ ℘(X) is a basis  if finite intersections of members of B are also unions of elements of B.) Now we can prove topology generated by a basis B consists of only those elements which are arbitary union of elements of B.**

But in generalised distributive law we use cartesian product and for this to be non empty we have to AC. Hence using the fact about basis we use AC. Is there any other proof which don't use AC?

Comment: AC is not used here.

Answer (score 1):

You're not making any choices, so you don't appeal to the axiom of choice. You just close $S$ under finite intersections, and then close this under unions. The axiom of choice is used, at best, to make some sort of cardinality arguments. But we don't care about that.

In here we don't really need to make any appeal to the axiom of choice regarding the distributivity, since the intersections are finite. Again, the simplest way to see this would be to see that you can first close under finite intersections (which we can do by induction, without appealing to choice) and then under unions (which is really just a single step).

Comment: So you mean to say while proving general distributive law, we don't use axiom of choice(but only notation of generalized cartesian product)

Comment: Okay, I'm not 100% sure about the general case of distributivity. But in this case you certainly don't make any appeal to the axiom of choice.

Comment: Can you please provide me some proof of this fact of basis. Because I have done proof is dependent on generalized distributive law(which also I am not sure whether dependent on AC or not but will figure it out soon as I expect)

Comment: Of what fact? That closing a basis under unions gives the topology? Here is a proof: by definition of a basis. $\square$

Comment: No tolopogy generated will be intersection of all topology containing B. Now you taking arbitary union of arbitary sets of B and saying just using def but how to write. I can't see any other option than using distributive law. Can you please write a proof(which would be much helpful)

Comment: thanks I got your hint also. Actually I was using wrong definition(equivalent definition for basis) so was not getting the point and proof I have done was also wrong as def was wrong. But it's okay now